# How to extract latest records in a table when filtering by column values

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table called `runs` as follows:

| id | job_id | command_id | type | input | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 875 | 61 | 25 | Pre | show name | 2022-08-08 07:36:14 |
| 876 | 61 | 26 | Pre | show dob | 2022-08-08 07:36:18 |
| 877 | 61 | 25 | Post | show name | 2022-08-08 07:37:00 |
| 878 | 61 | 26 | Post | show dob | 2022-08-08 07:37:03 |
| 879 | 61 | 25 | Post | show name | 2022-08-10 00:18:25 |
| 880 | 61 | 25 | Post | show name | 2022-08-10 00:20:27 |
| 891 | 61 | 26 | Post | show dob | 2022-08-10 00:20:30 |

I am trying to construct a SQL query to extract the latest record for each `input in ("show name", "show dob")`, where `type in ("Pre", "Post")` and `job_id = 61`.

This is the final result I am expecting:

| id | job_id | command_id | type | input | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 875 | 61 | 25 | Pre | show name | 2022-08-08 07:36:14 |
| 876 | 61 | 26 | Pre | show dob | 2022-08-08 07:36:18 |
| 880 | 61 | 25 | Post | show name | 2022-08-10 00:20:27 |
| 891 | 61 | 26 | Post | show dob | 2022-08-10 00:20:30 |

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
SELECT id, job_id, command_id, type, input, max(created_at) as created_at
FROM runs
WHERE job_id = 61
AND input IN ("show name", "show dob")
GROUP BY job_id, type, input
ORDER BY command_id ASC
```